# R: Use dplyr to merge dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

Here, the `bipolar` dataframe is a combination of the `dat` dataframe and a new `Indication` column derived from the `ann` dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
bipolar <- ann %>% select(FID=Database_ID, Indication=Profile) %>% (mutate(Indication=recode(Indication, "Unaffected control"="0/1", "BP"="1/2")) %>% inner_join(dat,.,by="FID")
```

Now, I want to modify the code above to add the `sex` and `Left_Brain` columns to `bipolar` dataframe.

`dat` dataframe

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(FID = c("AC13", "AC14", "AC15", "AC18", "AC19",
"AC1", "AC20", "AC21", "AC23", "AC24", "AC27", "AC29", "AC2",
"AC30", "AC32", "AC33", "AC34", "AC35", "AC36", "AC38", "AC42",
"AC43", "AC46", "AC48", "AC49", "AC50", "AC51", "AC52", "AC53",
"AC54", "AC56", "AC57", "AC58", "AC5", "AC60", "AC61", "AC62",
"AC63", "AC64", "AC65", "AC67", "AC69", "AC6", "AC70", "AC71",
"AC72", "AC74", "AC76", "AC77", "AC79", "AC80", "AC83", "AC84",
"AC86", "AC89", "AC8", "AC90", "AC91", "AC102", "AC103", "AC104",
"AC105", "AC16", "AC95", "AC96", "AC99", "DE10", "DE12", "DE13",
"DE14", "DE16", "DE17", "DE22", "DE23", "DE27", "DE36", "DE37",
"DE38", "DE39", "DE3", "DE40", "DE45", "DE46", "DE47", "DE4",
"DE50", "DE51", "DE52", "DE55", "DE57", "DE59", "DE7", "DE32",
"DE43"), IID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L), SOL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), C1 = c(-0.0285172, -0.0422061, -0.0135105, 0.0335788,
0.00453814, -0.0196805, 0.00871406, -0.0359998, 0.00776039, -0.0152431,
-0.0157209, 0.0235421, -0.0292564, 0.000164687, -0.0104566, -0.0078923,
-0.011623, 0.0173727, 0.00327281, -0.0101589, -0.00564814, 0.0232102,
0.00209183, -0.0245178, 0.0295213, -0.0012923, 0.00775297, 0.019803,
0.00521905, 0.0143496, 0.0243968, 0.0403667, 0.0420627, -0.0234294,
-0.00923894, 0.00216892, -0.0174861, 0.000902948, 0.0250136,
0.131506, 0.036772, -0.0314508, 0.0014534, 0.0123288, 0.0152248,
0.030759, 0.029896, 0.0257204, -0.0132957, -0.00942661, 0.0286468,
0.0297961, -0.0225471, 0.0185018, -0.0103523, -0.00141674, -0.00553813,
0.0141762, 0.0254432, -0.0124213, -0.0220576, 0.0278842, 0.00114805,
-0.013759, 0.00493565, -0.0146888, -0.00463272, -0.0332577, -0.0200095,
0.00230828, -0.0232427, 0.00433733, -0.0244282, -0.0245909, 0.0155191,
0.00425367, 0.00868522, -0.0347233, 0.00191488, -0.0154211, 0.0154046,
-0.00126067, 0.00826277, -0.0124104, -0.0136281, -0.023651, 0.00853699,
-0.0373163, 0.0147421, -0.0425991, -0.0198727, -0.0197213, -0.0115728,
-0.0127898), C2 = c(0.00450319, 0.00394058, -0.0316527, 0.00310475,
0.016075, 0.0108606, 0.0195024, -0.0109932, 0.02644, 0.00177053,
-0.0180791, -0.0128455, -0.0353571, 0.00868615, 0.0278649, -0.0143205,
0.0198699, 0.00600335, 0.00636933, -0.0245385, 0.0247255, -0.0019047,
0.00418658, -0.0106317, 0.0329249, -0.0490193, -0.0322256, -0.00525161,
0.0127281, -0.0210357, 0.048556, -0.0157994, 0.0225328, 0.0420733,
-0.0722942, 0.0117474, -0.00108231, -0.053874, -0.0351118, 0.000781904,
-0.0188162, -0.0214653, 0.0150199, 0.0339645, -0.0335628, -0.0151206,
0.0163763, -0.015727, -0.0232298, 0.0172519, 0.0348876, -0.026288,
0.0383726, -0.018123, 0.0200251, -0.0246757, 0.0184051, 0.0249351,
-0.00324928, 0.0129067, -0.0143993, -0.00150337, -0.00089652,
-0.0477761, 0.00873251, -0.0184572, 0.00115896, 0.0252723, -0.0188119,
0.0403222, -0.00957213, -0.0280059, 0.0183744, -0.025548, 0.021987,
0.0268481, -0.0267149, 0.00712551, -0.0115199, 0.00559716, 0.00779719,
-0.0181187, -0.0182654, -0.0263084, 0.00126466, 0.0397802, 0.0457278,
0.0098323, -0.00865206, 0.0248558, -0.0163334, 0.00451314, 0.0337946,
0.0267819)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -94L))
```

The `Database_ID` and `Profile` columns in the `ann` dataframe (there are other columns in the `ann` dataframe...refer to below)

```
> dput(ann[c("Database_ID","Profile")])
structure(list(Database_ID = c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13",
"AC14", "AC15", "AC17", "AC18", "AC19", "AC1", "AC20", "AC21",
"AC22", "AC23", "AC24", "AC25", "AC26", "AC27", "AC29", "AC2",
"AC30", "AC31", "AC32", "AC33", "AC34", "AC35", "AC36", "AC37",
"AC38", "AC39", "AC3", "AC40", "AC41", "AC42", "AC43", "AC45",
"AC46", "AC47", "AC48", "AC49", "AC50", "AC51", "AC52", "AC53",
"AC54", "AC55", "AC56", "AC57", "AC58", "AC5", "AC60", "AC61",
"AC62", "AC63", "AC64", "AC65", "AC66", "AC67", "AC69", "AC6",
"AC70", "AC71", "AC72", "AC73", "AC74", "AC75", "AC76", "AC77",
"AC78", "AC79", "AC7", "AC80", "AC81", "AC82", "AC83", "AC84",
"AC86", "AC87", "AC88", "AC89", "AC8", "AC90", "AC91", "AC92",
"AC9", "AC100", "AC101", "AC102", "AC103", "AC104", "AC105",
"AC16", "AC68", "AC93", "AC94", "AC95", "AC96", "AC97", "AC99",
"DE10", "DE12", "DE13", "DE14", "DE15", "DE16", "DE17", "DE18",
"DE19", "DE1", "DE20", "DE21", "DE22", "DE23", "DE25", "DE26",
"DE27", "DE2", "DE33", "DE34", "DE35", "DE36", "DE37", "DE38",
"DE39", "DE3", "DE40", "DE41", "DE42", "DE44", "DE45", "DE46",
"DE47", "DE48", "DE49", "DE4", "DE50", "DE51", "DE52", "DE53",
"DE54", "DE55", "DE56", "DE57", "DE58", "DE59", "DE60", "DE7",
"DE9", "DE29", "DE30", "DE32", "DE43", "DE5"), Profile = c("Schiz.",
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "BP",
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "Schiz.",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control",
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "BP",
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"BP", "BP", "Dep.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "BP", "Dep.", "Schiz.",
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Dep.", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "BP",
"Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.",
"Dep.", "BP", "Dep.", "BP", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Dep.",
"BP", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.")), row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24",
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35",
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46",
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57",
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68",
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79",
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90",
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100",
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109",
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118",
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127",
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136",
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145",
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153"), class = "data.frame")
```

There are other columns in `ann`, which I don't need.

```
> dput(head(ann))
structure(list(Database_ID = c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13",
"AC14", "AC15"), Collection_type = c("Array", "Array", "Array",
"Array", "Array", "Array"), Age = c(40L, 51L, 19L, 49L, 48L,
44L), Round_Age = c(40L, 50L, 20L, 50L, 50L, 45L), sex = c("M",
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F"), race = c("White", "White", "White",
"White", "White", "White"), Profile = c("Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"BP", "BP", "Unaffected control"), DSM_IV = c(295.9, 295.9, 295.9,
296.44, 296.7, NA), Axis_I_Primary_Dx = c("SCHIZ UNDIFF", "SCHIZ UNDIFF",
"SCHIZ UNDIFF", "BP I", "BP I", "CONTROL"), PMI = c(34L, 43L,
28L, 19L, 18L, 28L), Brain_PH = c(6.18, 6.63, 6.73, 5.87, 6.5,
6.59), Left_Brain = c("Fixed", "Frozen", "Frozen", "Fixed", "Frozen",
"Fixed"), Suicide_Status = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"
), Psychotic_Feature = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Unknown",
"No"), Rate_Of_Death = c("Possible anoxia at death (e.g., CO poisoning or pneumonia)",
"Sudden", "Sudden", "Sudden", "Sudden", "Sudden"), Exacerbation = c("No evidence of exacerbation",
"No evidence of exacerbation", "No evidence of exacerbation",
"Definite", "No evidence of exacerbation", "Unknown"), Smoking_At_TOD = c("Yes",
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Unknown"), Lifetime_Alcohol_Use = c("Moderate drinking in present (same as above, for recent period)",
"Moderate drinking in present (same as above, for recent period)",
"Social (1?2 drinks/day)", "Little or none (less than 1 drink/day)",
"Social (1?2 drinks/day)", "Moderate drinking in present (same as above, for recent period)"
), Lifetime_Drug_Use = c("Moderate drug use in present", "Social",
"Heavy drug use in present", "Little or none", "Moderate drug use in present",
"Little or none"), Lifetime_Antipsychotics = c(75000L, 130000L,
2500L, 4000L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
"6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It looks like you need one of the joining functions. Have you tried reading the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html)?

Comment: @AndreaM I tried but keep getting errors

Comment: Please edit the post to show the code with your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you could have pulled these in when you created bipolar from `ann` and `dat` (See bottom), but you can reach back into `ann', and pull those additional columns into` bipolar` like this:

```
left_join(
  bipolar,
  ann %>%
    select(Database_ID,sex,Left_Brain),
  by=c("FID"="Database_ID")
)
```

Your original creation of `bipolar` could have included `sex` and `Left_Brain` in the select statement:

```
bipolar <- ann %>%
  select(FID=Database_ID,Indication=Profile, sex, Left_Brain) %>% 
  mutate(Indication=recode(Indication,"Unaffected control"="0/1", "BP"="1/2")) %>% 
  inner_join(dat, ., by="FID")
```